# CartoDB Torque animation running longer than 'duration' value in CartoDB editor

Tags: carto, animation, torque

I'm creating a time series Torque animation with CartoDB, using data that spans a one week period. I've noticed that the animation is running longer than the value that 'duration' is set to in the CartoDB editor. This is true no matter what value I use for the duration. For example, if I set duration to 30 seconds, the animation actually takes about 35 seconds to complete one full cycle. If I set it to 15 seconds, it seems to take about 17.5 seconds.

The map and data can be viewed [here](http://cdb.io/1Eo156L).

The relevant CartoCSS code is

```
Map {
-torque-frame-count:1024;
-torque-animation-duration:30;
-torque-time-attribute:"timestamp";
-torque-aggregation-function:"count(cartodb_id)";
-torque-resolution:2;
-torque-data-aggregation:linear;
}
```

Does anyone have experience with this issue or thoughts on what might be causing it?

Answer (score 1):

This seems an actual issue in CartoDB side. I have reported it in the Torque repo: https://github.com/CartoDB/torque/issues/214